# Fluent Nhibernate - Saving child object without references

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, fluent-nhibernate-mapping

I have the following maps in my solution

```
public BlogMap() {
    Table("Blogs");
    LazyLoad();
    Id(x => x.BlogId).GeneratedBy.Identity().Column("BlogId");
    Map(x => x.BlogName).Column("BlogName").Not.Nullable();
    Map(x => x.BlogCreateDate).Column("BlogCreateDate");
    Map(x => x.PostCount).Column("PostCount");
    HasMany(x => x.BlogPosts).KeyColumn("BlogId");
}

public BlogPostMap() {
    Table("BlogPosts");
    LazyLoad();
    CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.PostId, "PostId").KeyProperty(x => x.BlogId,`enter code here` "BlogId");
    References(x => x.Blog).Column("BlogId");
    Map(x => x.PostText).Column("PostText");
    Map(x => x.CreateDate).Column("CreateDate");
}
```

One Blog may contain many BlogPosts

I am trying to create a new BlogPost and save it to the database. Below is how I'm trying to do it and it does not work.

```
BlogPost newbgPost = new BlogPost();
newbgPost.BlogId = currMasterBlogId;
newbgPost.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
newbgPost.PostText = newPostText;
newbgPost.PostId = newPostId+1;

repBlogPost.Save(newbgPost);
```

The above code works if I remove `References(x => x.Blog).Column("BlogId");` in my BlogPost Map.

I understand that the new BlogPost is looking for a reference in Blog , can I do it  by  using the `newbgPost.BlogId = currMasterBlogId;` which is basically the BlogId that I want  BlogPost to refer to.

Below is the BlogPost class

```
public class BlogPost {
        public virtual int PostId { get; set; }
        public virtual int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual Blog Blog { get; set; }
        public virtual string PostText { get; set; }
        public virtual System.Nullable<System.DateTime> CreateDate { get; set; }
        #region NHibernate Composite Key Requirements
        public override bool Equals(object obj) {
            if (obj == null) return false;
            var t = obj as BlogPost;
            if (t == null) return false;
            if (PostId == t.PostId && BlogId == t.BlogId)
                return true;

            return false;
        }
        public override int GetHashCode() {
            int hash = 13;
            hash += PostId.GetHashCode();
            hash += BlogId.GetHashCode();

            return hash;
        }
        #endregion
    }
```

Blog class:

```
  public class Blog {
        public Blog() {
            BlogPosts = new List<BlogPost>();
        }
        public virtual int BlogId { get; set; }
        public virtual string BlogName { get; set; }
        public virtual System.Nullable<System.DateTime> BlogCreateDate { get; set; }
        public virtual System.Nullable<int> PostCount { get; set; }
        public virtual IList<BlogPost> BlogPosts { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you are trying to create a relationship between a parent and child you must load the parent object rather than set the Id property of the field that manages the relationship.

Change your code as shown below in order to persist a new Blog Post:

```
BlogPost newbgPost = new BlogPost();
newbgPost.Blog = nhSession.Load<Blog>(currMasterBlogId);
newbgPost.CreateDate = DateTime.Now;
newbgPost.PostText = newPostText;
newbgPost.PostId = newPostId+1;

repBlogPost.Save(newbgPost);
```

nHibernate will take care of the relationship and update the `BlogId` field accordingly - you don't need to set that property.

You will also need to change your mapping so that the CompositeId is made up of both a PostId `property` and a Blog `reference` by altering the `KeyProperty` method to `KeyReference` shown below:

```
public BlogPostMap() {
    Table("BlogPosts");
    LazyLoad();
    Map(x => x.PostId);
    Map(x => x.BlogId).ReadOnly();
    CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.PostId).KeyReference(x => x.Blog);
    References(x => x.Blog).Column("BlogId");
    Map(x => x.PostText).Column("PostText");
    Map(x => x.CreateDate).Column("CreateDate");
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I tried your suggestion & managed to get the collection belonging to "newbgPost.Blog" from the database.When I tried to save the "newBlogPost" object I get the following error

"Invalid index 4 for this SqlParameterCollection with Count=4"

Below is the generic code to save my object 
        public void Save(T value)
        {
            using (var session = NHibernateHelper.OpenSession())
            {            using (var transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
                {
                    session.Save(value);
                    transaction.Commit();
                }}}

Comment: Because your Composite Id included a direct reference to BlogId this value was being set twice in the SQL being sent to the server, so  5 parameters were being passed where only 4 are required. See my edit which should fix your problem.

Comment: Updated to KeyReference but stepped into another problem "An association from the table BlogPosts refers to an unmapped class: System.Int32" while initiating the session factory.  
  Included the BlogPost class for reference.

Comment: I have adjusted the mapping in my answer to include a map definition for both BlogId and PostId. BlogId is marked as ReadOnly as the Reference to Blog handles the setting of this value.

Comment: Thanks again.Updated with your suggestion,but still face the same error "An association from the table BlogPosts refers to an unmapped class: System.Int32". I will also put up the Blog class in the question for now.

Answer (score 0):

Just clarifying that you can't make duplicate mappings between your CompositeId() and other mappings, i.e. Map(), References().

Once you include a property in a composite id, it is already mapped. So in the answer by CSL, you still need to remove 2 lines of code:

```
Map(x => x.PostId);
References(x => x.Blog).Column("BlogId");
```

The result should look like this:

```
public BlogPostMap() {
    Table("BlogPosts");
    LazyLoad();
    Map(x => x.BlogId).ReadOnly();
    CompositeId().KeyProperty(x => x.PostId).KeyReference(x => x.Blog);
    Map(x => x.PostText).Column("PostText");
    Map(x => x.CreateDate).Column("CreateDate");
}
```

Assuming the rest of the mapping is correct, thsi should work.